# Website setup - Cannot find server: Read error

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

We're trying to setup a test website to run in parallel with the live website. We are using port 81 assigned to a second domain.

The environment is a load balancer with two Windows 2012 servers running .NET 4

We are able to navigate to the website using localhost on each server if port 81 is not binded to a domain. As soon as we bind it to a domain it fails to load. The DNS for the domain is pointing to the same IP as the main website that is running on port 80.

Doing a traceroute shows that the domain reaches our server, yet it fails to load the content with the error "Cannot find server".

We ran out of ideas of what could be wrong.

---

EDIT:

At the bottom of the error message it says ***Read error*** and not the usual Connection error. Does anyone know what this means? I couldn't find anything online.

[image]

Comment: Is the load balancer set up for the new port 81 listeners?

Comment: Good question. The load balancer is managed by our hosting company and they said to have opened port 81 in its firewall. What are port listeners?